# Algebraic closureness and Hilbert Nullstellensatz

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

For a given field $k$, is the algebraic closureness of $k$ equivalent to the Hilbert Nullstellensatz in one dimension affine space?

Comment: Thank you very much @SassatelliGiulio.

Comment: Please post answers as answers, not as comments, so that they can be accepted and the questions don't stay (wrongly) in the list of unanswered questions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f \in K[X] \setminus K$ is a polynomial and the equation $I(V(f))=\sqrt{\langle f \rangle}$ holds, then $1 \notin \sqrt{\langle f \rangle} = I(V(f))$, hence $V(f) \neq \emptyset$, which means that $f$ has a root in $K$.